# Getting a connection timed out exception in webservices

Tags: java, web-services, exception, wsdl

I am getting the following exception when I try to submit a request through webservice.

The stack trace is as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
    at $Proxy40.externalSearchPerson(Unknown Source)
    at com.igniteibroker.Main.personSearch(Main.java:52)
    at com.igniteibroker.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:974)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)
    ... 15 more
```

please help me resolve this if you have identified the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check if the requested URL is available or not ? connection timeout is caused by either an unavailable URI or a slow connection. Could you check if you could connect to the requested URI directly (i.e with web browser).

Comment: Hi Ali HAMDI, I am getting the same error when I tried with SoapUI tool as well.

And internet issue can be completely ruled out

Comment: Then you have to check the status of the web service , it may be unavailable or down.

Comment: Your request is then taking taking too much time. You should consider increase timeout.

Comment: Hi Ali HAMDI, I tried to load the WSDL file in the SoapUI. Surprisingly it gave me "java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;"

Comment: It may be corrupted , could you check the validity of your WSDL ?

Comment: Yes I will resume debugging this tomo 8 IST. will be gone till then Thanks Ali

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jersey.api

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form;


ClientResponse response = null;
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
/*client.setReadTimeout(30);*/
/*client.setConnectTimeout(interval)*/
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
```

In Client class There is method client.setConnectTimeout(interval) if u not set this method then it will try to make connection infinite time.

Comment: Hi I have the connection timeout to 2 minutes. and I use javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", "200000"

Comment: basically this method accept value in Millisecond if assign null or 0 then automatically it will be interval of infinite decelerated .

Answer (score 0):

I tried to load the `WSDL` file in the `SoapUI`.

Surprisingly it gave me "`java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;`"

I think you are using `https wsdl url` to load this `webservice`.

It would be password protected.Save your `wsdl` file locally on your machine and try to load `wsdl` file instead of url in soap ui.

And while sending request at h`ttps endpoint` , you need to provide username and password. 
In `soapui` you can fill username and password in request property at bottom left corner.